# Dynamically and Statically allocated Array elements calculation?

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there any way to calculate the number of elements in a dynamically allocated array ? using statically allocated array its not usefully(it gives me error of stack overflow) because i need to allocate a buffer size to store data of 100,000 double values(100000*8=800000 bytes). Anyway i am failed to do so with static array but really i dont want to allocate such big size buffer on Stack instead Heap will be preferred.

So here is what i did.

Statically allocated array, here size is that what i actually needed to me(it fails certainly with this case) but i tried then with some smaller size and it works and printed number of elements for me `but this is not what i want i need something which can count how many elements are actually entered by for loop not just return whole size (800010*8)` i.e something like we do for `char buffer[1000]` and then `strlen(buffer)`.

```
srand (time(0));
double arr[800010];
 for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{    
arr[i] = (rand()%10000)+(134.234*i); 
std::cout<<"is"<<arr[i]<<std::endl;

}
int numelements = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
std::cout<<"num elements are"<<numelements*8;//multiplied by 8 is size of double;
```

Dynamic allocation is good no problem in memory allocation on heap but `"num elements are" = 0` ? and if some one recommending using `std::vector<double>m_vector` please suggest how i can pass it as an array because `m_vector.data()` function is  works only with text data, is it ? or if any idea how can i do count the actual number of elements ? please don't say do `100000*8`. I am looking for some logical way to do it.

```
    srand (time(0));
    double *arr = new double[800010];
   for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {    
    arr[i] = (rand()%10000)+(134.234*i); 
    std::cout<<"is"<<arr[i]<<std::endl;

    }
    int numelements = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    std::cout<<"num elements are"<<numelements*8;
```

Comment: What don't you understand about vectors? Sounds like vectors are the exact answer to your question...

Comment: _'`m_vector.data()` function is works only with **text data**, is it ?'_ Eh, what??

Comment: std::vector has a function size() which will give you the vector size.

Comment: You're allocating incorrectly, or rather, too much.  `double * arr = new[800010]` gets you 800010 doubles, not 100000.

Comment: also `sieof(arr)` is a size of a pointer, not whole array.

Comment: `m_vector.data()` returns a `value_type *`, which would be a `double*`, and has nothing to do with text specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of allocating arrays using `new[]` use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. It will track the size for you and take care of freeing up the underlying memory.

For example:

```
std::vector<double> arr(100000);
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
{    
  arr[i] = (rand()%10000) + (134.234*i); 
  std::cout << "is" <<arr [i] << std::endl;

}

int numelements = arr.size();
```

Comment: Can you please mention what can be used used to hold all the elements data. Like we use for char type vector and use data() to hold    the data elements.

Comment: @user3232405 `std::vector<>::data()` isn't meant to be used for the operations you want to do. Use `resize()` and `size()` to allocate/determine the number of `double` items you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want a c-string-like representation of an array of doubles you might store a NaN as terminating element:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::size_t nan_terminated_length(const double* d) {
    std::size_t result = 0;
    while(d[result] == d[result]) ++result; // C++11: std::isnan
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::istringstream input("1.0 2.0 3.0");
    std::vector<double> buffer;
    buffer.reserve(1024);

    double d;
    while(input >> d) {
        buffer.push_back(d);
    }
    buffer.push_back(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());

    std::cout
        << "Number of elements: "
        << nan_terminated_length(buffer.data())
        << " which is (in this case) equal to the"
                   " size of the vector minus one: "
        << buffer.size() - 1
        << '\n';
}
```